# Jquery what is the difference between $(#id) and $([id=])

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was a bit confused when I encountered this in my programm. So I was wondering if anyone knew what could be the deal here. I am fairly new to Jquery after all.

Why does:

```
$('[id="' + nameOftheID + '"]').append("Append some text");
```

work for me.

Yet

```
$("#" + nameOftheID).append("Append some text");
```

does not work for me.
In this case the 'nameOftheID' is a var that is exactly the same as the ID of the **span** I am trying to append some text to (I tested and confirmed this in debugging). Why is it that the normal # selector for selection based on ID's does not append the text for me. but the other method does?

My code works in the end. I just want to know why A works and B doesnt.

The name of my ID is "Ruleset[0].Conditions[0]"

Comment: first one is the name value selector and second one is id selector.

Comment: Does the `nameOftheID` contain any special characters like `[]` If so you need to escape them.

Comment: Show a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: What is the value of `nameOftheID`?

Comment: Yes it does contain characters like []. The ID is "Ruleset[0].Conditions[0]" as an . Could that interfere with the selector?

Comment: Yes that is why the second code doesn't work and the first does.

Comment: Is it bad practice to have [ and ] in my ID's and should I remove it? Or it is okay to keep selecting on names instead of id's?

Comment: @Leonard: "*..Is it bad practice to have [ and ] in my ID's and should I remove it..*": Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use \\ for escape characters

```
#Ruleset\\[0\\]\.Conditions\\[0\\]
```

Below is the differnce for two selectors :

```
$("#" + nameOftheID).append("Append som text");
```

Above code is to select element by ID and here syntax is to use `#`.

And

```
$('[id="' + nameOftheID + '"]').append("Append some text");
```

This comes under attribute selector, where you can restrict the selection for specific tag like below

```
$('input[id="inputId"]').append("Append some text");// here it will check the id attribute of input tag only
```

Also, attribute selectors can be use to find elements with value start with some text like find input with id start with 'nameOf'

```
$('input[id^="nameOf"]').append("Append some text");
```

Hence attribute selectors can be used for get elements with more filtering or for more precise selections. Please find more on selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

> The ID is `Ruleset[0].Conditions[0]` as an example

Your ID contains characters with special meaning in a selector.

If you just prefix that with a `#` then the `[` will start an attribute selector and the `.` will start a class selector. You have to escape characters with special meaning in a selector if you use them in an id selector.

```
#Ruleset\[0\]\.Conditions\[0\]
```

Note that you must include the selector escape characters *in the string* and that `\` is an escape character for JavaScript string literals (which will require escaping itself in order to make `\` part of the string).

Those characters don't have special meaning inside a quoted attribute selector.

I prefer to avoid the problem by keeping characters with special meaning out of id values in the first place.

Comment: You need double \\ to escape

Answer (score 0):

> My code works in the end. I just want to know why A works and B doesnt.

Sizzle (the part of jQuery that handles `$(...)` things) assumes an ID to be the following:

```
"(?:\\\\.|[\\w-]|[^\\x00-\\xa0])+"
```

That is, an escaped character, or a word char, or an ASCII char higher than `\xA0`. That excludes all punctuation and regex metacharacters  like `[`. So when you something like `#foo[]` to the `$` function, it won't be recognized and throw the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #foo[]
```

The attribute selector, on the other side, only requires a quoted string and doesn't care about its content.

Answer (score 0):

As i see in the comments section that your span's `id` holds some special chars like `[]` brackets:

This code

```
$('[id="' + nameOftheID + '"]')
```

represents like this:

```
$('[id="Ruleset[0].Conditions[0]"]') // works because of string representation.
```

This represents the id as a string so it works but for the other one this is not the case, for that id representation you have to escape your special chars with double slashes `\\`