# Difference between $("#id") and $("[id=]")

Tags: jquery

In my page, due to some reason (which I do not find relevant to the topic hence not explaining) a div gets duplicated and two divs with same id are generated in my html. While writing jquery code to remove all divs except topmost, I found that `$("#id")` was returning me just 1 element(note: there are two divs with same id now) whereas `$("[id=]")` was returning me `2`. So finally my code worked with `$("[id=]")` but not with `$("#id")`.
Any reason why? Is it that `$("#id")` returns only the first element it finds with specified id?

Please note that I have already come across a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733990/jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id/39566320#39566320) which has a similar question but does not answer my query

Comment: Read Official docs https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ and https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: yes, `$("#id")` will always gives you single result. Just like `document.getelementBuId`. Check `$("body #id")` and i am sure you will get result count 2 similar to `$("[id=]")`

Comment: Hi Rajaprabhu, see you after long time in SO

Comment: If you have control over what is generating the HTML you need to fix the generation of duplicate ids. While your web page or app may appear to work, its behavior is not garunteed to be consitant. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: @shubha Please refer : https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: this question already exists in SO. I will close it as duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery what is the difference between $(#id) and $(\[id=\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733990/jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id)

Comment: this link has the answer, refer it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733990/jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-id-and-id

Comment: This is a good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498579/how-jquery-works-when-there-are-multiple-elements-with-the-same-id

Answer (score 4):

The thing is `$("#id")` will always gives you single result like `document.getelementById()` however when you do `$("[id=]")` you are finding all elements with a given attibute as `id` so it returns you multiple elements since it doesn't use the javascript `document.getelementById()` now.

`$("[id=]")` is something that you use when you want to select some elements form your document that follow some rules like

> Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given substring.

> Attribute Contains Word Selector [name~=”value”]

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

> Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]

Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

etc.

For more information see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
However in you HTML you should ideally keep the `id` to be **unique**. If you want multiple elements to have same id then use `class` instead.