# How to add multiple items to a selector?

Tags: jquery

I have a field group where I want to add multiple values selected by the user. I have been able to create an array with all the selected values but I am unable to add those values to the selector. Here is the piece of code.

```
    console.log(allValues)
    jQuery('input[name="myServices"]').join(allValues);//.add(allItems)
    console.log("Befrejkjk"+document.getElementById('myServices').value
```

Doing console.log(allValues) prints an array with multiple values but the next statement just adds the first value of allItems. Please suggest.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566764/difference-between-id-and-id#39566764

Comment: what type of input have you got there ?

Comment: Do you need `jQuery('input[name="myServices"]').val(allValues.join(''))`?

Comment: here `selector` means HTML dropdown box?

Comment: @Satpal let me try out that

Comment: @Satpal No that's not working